# Solr - How do I sort by geospatial distance and return the distance?

Tags: solr, lucene, geospatial

Doing a Bbox search with only location is returning accurate data; but if we add more search parameters, the returned distance score gets wrong-

For e.g-

**case 1:**

[http://devtsg.truckertools.com/solr-4.4.0/collection1/select?wt=json&rows=1&fl=*,score&sort=score asc&q={!bbox score=distance sfield=geo pt=33.3232,-83.383 d=150}](http://devtsg.truckertools.com/solr-4.4.0/collection1/select?wt=json&rows=1&fl=%2a,score&sort=score%20asc&q=%7B!bbox%20score=distance%20sfield=geo%20pt=33.3232,-83.383%20d=150%7D)

-it returns correct distance for the store- **"score":0.02656421**

**case 2:**

But if I add another checking, with Bbox, it returns wrong distance-score

[http://devtsg.truckertools.com/solr-4.4.0/collection1/select?wt=json&rows=1&fl=*,score&sort=score asc&q=({!bbox score=distance sfield=geo pt=33.3232,-83.383 d=150} AND *:*)](http://devtsg.truckertools.com/solr-4.4.0/collection1/select?wt=json&rows=1&fl=%2a,score&sort=score%20asc&q=%28%7B!bbox%20score=distance%20sfield=geo%20pt=33.3232,-83.383%20d=150%7D%20AND%20%2a%3a%2a%29)

-the above one returns **"score":0.7258905** , which is wrong. It should be same as the above one.

**case 3:**

Just to make sure, have added a checking with the id of the store-

[http://devtsg.truckertools.com/solr-4.4.0/collection1/select?wt=json&rows=1&fl=*,score&sort=score asc&q=({!bbox score=distance sfield=geo pt=33.3232,-83.383 d=150} AND id:9220)](http://devtsg.truckertools.com/solr-4.4.0/collection1/select?wt=json&rows=1&fl=%2a,score&sort=score%20asc&q=%28%7B!bbox%20score=distance%20sfield=geo%20pt=33.3232,-83.383%20d=150%7D%20AND%20id:9220%29)

-now this one also returns wrong distance- **"score":9.05333**

Am not getting whats going wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put each 'AND'ed part of your query into Solr filter queries ('fq' param), and leave 'q' for keyword search relevancy.  In your field list ('fl' param) you can put a function query to return the distance: `fl=*,dist:geodist()`. Other params like 'pt' and 'sfield' are required.  To sort, use `sort=geodist() asc`.

However, you can't use the `geodist()` function query with a spatial "RPT" field in versions of Solr prior to v4.5. I see you are using 4.4.  If you need to sort on an RPT field (only needed if you have multiple locations) in Solr 4.2 thru 4.4 then you have to approach this differently, and your attempt is close.  I suggest always using 'q', and 'fq' params as you normally should use them (keyword and filters, respectively).  Consider this echoParams output of my query to Solr:

```
  "indent":"true",    
  "wt":"json",  
  "sort":"query({!bbox v='' filter=false score=distance}) asc",
  "fl":"*,score,dist:query({!bbox v='' filter=false score=distance})",
  "sfield":"geo",
  "pt":"33.3232,-83.383",
  "d":"150",
  "q":"*:*",
  "fq":"{!bbox}",
  "fq":"id:9220"
```

Yeah, it's ugly. Again, as of Solr 4.5 you no longer have to resort to this.

By the way, the behavior you see is actually not a bug. You need to compose your query differently to get the results you want.